# Is there a way to set the root directory of explorer (netrw) to the working dirctory of the current window in Vim?

Tags: vim

For example, there are two splited windows on screen, explorer at `some/path` and a file with path `another/path/123.txt`
and I want to set explorer path to `another/path` by do something in `123.txt`

Is there a way to set the root directory of explorer (netrw) to the working dirctory of the current window in Vim?
(Maybe there is a way in NERDtree can do something similar to what I hope to do, just out of curious)

thanks for answering.
and my English isn't very good, sorry for that

Comment: Not sure if there's a cleaner way, but seems like with vimscripting, you could write a script function that 1) gets current directory of 123.txt, 2) jumps to netrw buffer, 3) executes ":e <directory of 123.txt>"

Comment: @wxz That is good idea, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to close the tree explorer window and then split+explore from the `123.txt` file

```
:only|Sexplore %:h<cr>
<c-w>o:sp %:h<cr>
```

A semi-related simple mapping (and setting) which copies Tim Pope's [vim-vinegar](https://github.com/tpope/vim-vinegar)'s `-` for fast directory exploring is approximately:

```
noremap - :e %:h<cr>
let g:netrw_banner = 0
```

With this you would do `<c-w>o<c-w>s-`

For more help see:

```
:h :only
:h :Sex
:h :_%
:h ::h
```

Comment: This way is simple and intuitive, I will use this mathod. Thanks!